Comparing 3 numbers (every number is three-digit) in TASM 8086
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg1
int 21h

; Read 1st number
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
mov bh, al

mov ah, 01h
int 21h
mov bl, al

mov ax,bx
and ax,0F0Fh
aad         ;0X0X --> 00XX
mov bl,al       ;1ST NUMBER

mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg2
int 21h
; Read 2nd number
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
mov ch, al

mov ah, 01h
int 21h
mov cl, al

mov ax,cx
and ax,0F0Fh
aad             ;0X0X --> 00XX
mov bh,al       ;2ND NUMBER

mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg3
int 21h
; Read 3rd number
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
mov ch, al

mov ah, 01h
int 21h
mov cl, al

mov ax,cx
and ax,0F0Fh
aad             ;0X0X --> 00XX
mov ch,al       ;3ND NUMBER

mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg5
int 21h

; Compare numbers
cmp bl, bh
jg first_compare
jl second_compare

first_compare:
    cmp bl,ch
    jg first_greatest
    jl third_greatest
    
second_compare:
    cmp bh,ch
    jg second_greatest
    jl third_greatest

first_greatest:
    call num_greates
    mov ax,0000h
        mov al, bl
    call greatestnum
    jmp done
    
second_greatest:
    call num_greates
    mov ax,0000h
    mov al, bh
    call greatestnum
    jmp done
    
third_greatest:
    call num_greates
    mov ax,0000h
    mov al, ch
    call greatestnum
    jmp done
    
greatestnum proc        ;Convert to ASCII then print
    aam
    add ax, 3030h
    mov bx, ax
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, bh
    int 21h
    mov dl, bl
    int 21h
    ret
greatestnum endp
    
num_greates proc
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, msg4
    int 21h
    ret
num_greates endp

I tried to create 2 digit comparison then print the two-digit greatest number. I have no clue how to compare the third-digit number then print it. I think I should use shl to move the values after I : "aad" then "mov bl,al" to store the 3rd digit then I should compare them by 16 bits from another 16 bits, but the problem is there is no enough registers to store them

If you run out of registers, use memory. That said, you definitely have enough registers for 3 numbers. The common algorithm for string to number conversion is to multiply the current value by 10 and add the next digit. Repeat in a loop. PS: Do not use conflicting tags. Is it tasm or emu8086?

The solution depends on the upper limit for the three-digit number.
Three-digit numbers in the range 000 to 255
You can continue to work with the aad instruction and you won't encounter any register shortage because we can continue storing the successive numbers in BL, BH, and CH.
Code to add a third digit to the 1st number:
mov  ah, 09h
lea  dx, msg1
int  21h
mov  ah, 01h     ; Get 1st digit of 1st number
int  21h         ; -> AL
mov  cl, al      ; ['0','2']
mov  ah, 01h     ; Get 2nd digit of 1st number
int  21h         ; -> AL
mov  ah, cl
and  ax, 0F0Fh
aad
mov  cl, al      ; [0,25]
mov  ah, 01h     ; Get 3rd digit of 1st number
int  21h         ; -> AL
and  al, 0Fh
mov  ah, cl
aad
mov  BL, al      ; [0,255]

Use similar code for 2nd number (BH) and 3rd number (CH).
The part where you compare the numbers in turn is flawed:

You did not decide what to do when numbers are equal to each other. This inevitably leads to wrong results! Think about how jg and jl are not perfect opposites of each other. jge and jl are fine, and so would jg and jle be.
You're using too many conditional jumps here. It's much better to let the execution 'fall-through' wherever it can:

compare12:
  cmp  bl, bh
  jge  compare13
compare23:
  cmp  bh, ch
  jge  second_greatest
  jl   third_greatest
compare13:
  cmp  bl, ch
  jl   third_greatest
first_greatest:
  ...

Because now the number that you want displayed could exceed the value 99, you'll have to change the code in your greatestnum proc by the code snippet from an answer of mine to a question about converting a binary number into decimal and showing the answer in 3 digits.
Three-digit numbers in the range 000 to 999
Below I present a solution that continues to use the aad instruction for combining the most significant digits and that relies on one multiplication by 10 in order to add the least significant digit. Again no register shortage is to be expected. I'll store the successive numbers in BX, CX, and DX.
Code to add a third digit to the 1st number:
mov  ah, 09h
lea  dx, msg1
int  21h
mov  ah, 01h     ; Get 1st digit of 1st number
int  21h         ; -> AL
mov  BL, al      ; ['0','9']
mov  ah, 01h     ; Get 2nd digit of 1st number
int  21h         ; -> AL
mov  ah, BL
and  ax, 0F0Fh
aad
mov  BL, 10
mul  BL          ; -> AX = AL * BL = [0,99] * 10
mov  BX, AX      ; [0,990]
mov  ah, 01h     ; Get 3rd digit of 1st number
int  21h         ; -> AL
and  al, 0Fh
cbw
add  BX, ax      ; [0,999]

Use similar code for 2nd number (CX) and 3rd number (DX).
Because DX contains one of the number, you need to preserve its value around displaying msg5:
push dx
mov  ah, 09h
lea  dx, msg5
int  21h
pop  dx

Use the improved code for comparing the numbers and don't forget to change the register names form {BL,BH,CH} to {BX,CX,DX}.
Again, because now the number that you want displayed could exceed the value 99, you'll have to change the code in your greatestnum proc by a suitable code for printing the number held in AX. Get inspired by reading Displaying numbers with DOS.
